# iOS Framework build including Project headers when explicitly set as "Project" and not "Public"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, ios-frameworks

I have an iOS static library that I am working on with a separate target called 'Framework' which handles the build script to package the library up as a .framework.

However within the last day or so I must have messed something up since there are 5 or 6 private "Project" headers that are getting included as visible headers in the framework. I am positive that the "Headers" section includes the proper headers in the Public and Private sections.

Why is Xcode including my project headers in the framework build? How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Yeah, when you add/remove a public header, or change a public header to project, you should DELETE the .framework files and rebuild causing Xcode to regenerate them. Xcode does a lot of caching to prevent compiling same code multiple times which can cause this issue.